# Get Index of variables from stepAIC

Tags: r

I am regressing a gene on another gene subset. Then I use stepAIC to reduce the number of explanatory genes. How do I get the index of the NON-omitted variables, so that I could analyse them?

```
gene_subset=c(y=genes[,i], genes[,other_genes]);
reduced_model=stepAIC(y~.,data=gene_subset,trace=false);
```

Comment: Please provide [some example data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), and your expected output. What does "the index" refer to?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution that I got from r-help mail list, any other more efficient ways would be welcome.

```
# create example data frame
y <- rnorm(30)
gene_subset <- data.frame(y, x1=rnorm(30), x2=rnorm(30), x3=100*y+rnorm(30))

# fit a full linear model
fit <- lm(y ~ ., df)

# reduce the model
reduced_model <- stepAIC(fit, trace=FALSE)

# NON-omitted variables (excluding the response)
keepx <- names(reduced_model$model)[-1]
index <- match(keepx, names(gene_subset))
```